# Bean validation : Duplicate annotation Exception

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have defined this constraint :

```
@Size( min = 5 )
@NotBlank
@Pattern.List( {
        @Pattern( regexp = "(?=.*[0-9]).+", message = "au moins un chiffre" ),
        @Pattern( regexp = "(?=.*[a-z]).+", message = "au moins une lettre miniscule" ),
        @Pattern( regexp = "(?=.*[A-Z]).+", message = "au moins une lettre majiscule" ),
        @Pattern( regexp = "(?=.*[!@#$%^&*+=?-_()/\"\\.,<>~`;:]).+", message = "au moins un caractère spécial" ),
        @Pattern( regexp = "(?=\\S+$).+", message = "pas d'espace" )
} )
private String    password;
```

But when I send invalid password which not respect this constraint, I have the exception bellow :

```
java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface javax.validation.constraints.Pattern: @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(flags=[], groups=[], message=au moins une lettre miniscule, payload=[], regexp=(?=.*[a-z]).+)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.mapTypeAnnotations(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory.buildAnnotatedType(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.buildAnnotatedType(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotatedType(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findCascadingMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:614) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findPropertyMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:236) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getFieldMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:225) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:133) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:124) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(BeanMetaDataManager.java:220) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:187) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.lambda$getBeanMetaData$0(BeanMetaDataManager.java:160) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:6.0.7.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hum. So this is an Eclipse compiler bug (you might encounter it with another IDE using the Eclipse compiler).

Compiling with javac (e.g. if you do a mvn clean install) works without any issue.

**The only workaround you have is to upgrade to Hibernate Validator 6+ where all the constraint annotations are marked as repeatable.**

You can then do:

```
@Size( min = 5 )
@NotBlank
@Pattern( regexp = "(?=.*[0-9]).+", message = "au moins un chiffre" ),
@Pattern( regexp = "(?=.*[a-z]).+", message = "au moins une lettre miniscule" ),
@Pattern( regexp = "(?=.*[A-Z]).+", message = "au moins une lettre majiscule" ),
@Pattern( regexp = "(?=.*[!@#$%^&*+=?-_()/\"\\.,<>~`;:]).+", message = "au moins un caractère spécial" ),
@Pattern( regexp = "(?=\\S+$).+", message = "pas d'espace" )
private String    password;
```

without the List construct.

And in this case, the compiler works as expected (at least with Oxygen.3).

I'll open a bug at Eclipse, see if they can do something about it.

Update: the Eclipse issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533199

Comment: Yes, I'm not surprised though as we had quite a few compiler bugs with annotations in javac and the Eclipse compiler during the development of Hibernate Validator 6.0.x. Hopefully, it will get fixed at some point as it's quite annoying when you encounter one. In this case, you have an easy workaround, it's not always the case unfortunately...

Comment: Quick update: the Eclipse issue got confirmed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533199#c1 .

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. I use Spring Tool Suite and as it is based on Eclipse the problem is propagated. Fortunately your answer helped...

Comment: Four years and a half and Eclipse still have this bug. I have bumped into this recently and visiting the hyperlink provided I was able to see recent comments about it reporting the very same problem.